# Copy text contents with bullets in a textarea

Tags: jquery

When I try to copy the bullet-ed text from div and paste it to html textarea using jquery, it shows only the text and no bullets are showing. Are there any way I can do it? May be using jquery or any other method?

And also I only want to use textarea and no text editor like ckeditor and such.

It's as simple like this, this is my word text

• Some Text

• Some Text

But when I paste it in the text area it's just showing

Some Text

Some Text

I think jquery can help. But I'm unable to get the contents of clipboard, and even if some how I get it will the bullets be detected by javascript so that I can replace them with li tag. Any help!!!

Comment: You may try using a div instead of textarea

Comment: Are you using <ul><li></li>...</ul> within your div?

Comment: yes I am using ul><li></li>...</ul> within div

Answer (score 0):

```css
.text {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
Copy this
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div contenteditable='true' class="text">
  paste here ...
</div>
```

Comment: OP want to use Textarea.

Comment: @Manwal, kindly read the question carefully, OP wants formatting e.g.  bullets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to format your text with jQuery and transform into `&#8226;` or `&bull;` and instead textarea you can use div. In that case you ca play with all formats. Just use javascript or jQuery to send and recive data and replace characters.

**[-> Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)**

**[-> Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGHMk/)**