# JQUERY: textarea that only permits bullet points on typed or pasted text

Tags: jquery, tabs, contenteditable

```
   •    Test 1
       o    Test 1A
           o    Test 1AA
   •    Test 2
```

I want something like above in a textarea.

So when I save I get:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1A</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1AA</li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>Test 2</li>
</ul>
```

My research got me this:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/abhiagrawal87/m39xt/

   ```
   $(".todolist").focus(function() {
   if(document.getElementById('todolist').value === ''){
       document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
   }
   });
   $(".todolist").keyup(function(event){
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if(keycode == '13'){
       document.getElementById('todolist').value +='• ';
   }
   var txtval = document.getElementById('todolist').value;
   if(txtval.substr(txtval.length - 1) == '\n'){
       document.getElementById('todolist').value = txtval.substring(0,txtval.length - 1);
   }
   });
   ```
2. http://jsfiddle.net/jz6J5/

   ```
   $(document).delegate('#textbox', 'keydown', function(e) { 
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

     if (keyCode == 9) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
       var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

       // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
       $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                   + "\t"
                   + $(this).val().substring(end));

       // put caret at right position again
       $(this).get(0).selectionStart = 
       $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
     } 
   });
   ```
3. [Copy text contents with bullets in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099533/copy-text-contents-with-bullets-in-a-textarea)

   ```
   .text {
     border: 1px solid grey;
     padding: 2px 3px;
   }

   <ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
   <hr/>
   <div contenteditable='true' class="text">
     paste here ...
   </div>
   ```

All the code here did something that helped but putting it together is another thing. Some use div and others textarea.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
-Barry